# React Native App UI freezes, became unresponsive after updating xcode to 14.2

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, mobile

I tried creating the multi-language support react native app. This app currently runs on android and ios but on ios, it was working fine when I updated Xcode to 14.2 the app starts, the screen freezes, and became unresponsive.
Here is the code used.

Xcode logcat

```
Thread Performance Checker: Thread running at QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE waiting on a lower QoS thread running at QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT. Investigate ways to avoid priority inversions
PID: 97834, TID: 527115
Backtrace
=================================================================
3   planetTube                          0x0000000100c22b1c -[_RCTSRRunLoopThread runLoop] + 44
4   planetTube                          0x0000000100c2284c __49+[NSRunLoop(RCTSRWebSocket) RCTSR_networkRunLoop]_block_invoke + 116
5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103691d5c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103693800 _dispatch_once_callout + 80
7   planetTube                          0x0000000100c227b0 +[NSRunLoop(RCTSRWebSocket) RCTSR_networkRunLoop] + 84
8   planetTube                          0x0000000100c1c7ec -[RCTSRWebSocket _connect] + 68
9   planetTube                          0x0000000100c1b590 -[RCTSRWebSocket open] + 300
10  planetTube                          0x0000000100bfd9d0 -[RCTReconnectingWebSocket start] + 148
11  planetTube                          0x0000000100bed3bc -[RCTPackagerConnection init] + 404
12  planetTube                          0x0000000100bed208 __49+[RCTPackagerConnection sharedPackagerConnection]_block_invoke + 36
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103691d5c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103693800 _dispatch_once_callout + 80
15  planetTube                          0x0000000100bed1bc +[RCTPackagerConnection sharedPackagerConnection] + 84
16  planetTube                          0x0000000100c87964 -[RCTDevSettings initialize] + 148
17  planetTube                          0x0000000100bd69d0 -[RCTModuleData _initializeModule] + 96
18  planetTube                          0x0000000100bd6330 -[RCTModuleData setUpInstanceAndBridge:] + 2120
19  planetTube                          0x0000000100bd7de8 -[RCTModuleData instance] + 1168
20  planetTube                          0x0000000100b76f8c -[RCTCxxBridge moduleForName:lazilyLoadIfNecessary:] + 680
21  planetTube                          0x0000000100be0ba0 -[RCTModuleRegistry moduleForName:lazilyLoadIfNecessary:] + 128
22  planetTube                          0x0000000100be0b14 -[RCTModuleRegistry moduleForName:] + 48
23  planetTube                          0x0000000100c9bd64 -[RCTPerfMonitor devMenuItem] + 84
24  planetTube                          0x0000000100c9bc38 -[RCTPerfMonitor initialize] + 88
25  planetTube                          0x0000000100bd69d0 -[RCTModuleData _initializeModule] + 96
26  planetTube                          0x0000000100bd6330 -[RCTModuleData setUpInstanceAndBridge:] + 2120
27  planetTube                          0x0000000100bd8018 __25-[RCTModuleData instance]_block_invoke + 44
28  planetTube                          0x0000000100c409dc RCTUnsafeExecuteOnMainQueueSync + 52
29  planetTube                          0x0000000100bd7c88 -[RCTModuleData instance] + 816
30  planetTube                          0x0000000100b7b7f8 __49-[RCTCxxBridge _prepareModulesWithDispatchGroup:]_block_invoke + 156
31  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103690594 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
32  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103691d5c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
33  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001036a2978 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 1684
34  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001036a22d4 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 40
35  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000180372ca4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
36  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018036d360 __CFRunLoopRun + 1956
37  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018036c7a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 584
38  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000188ff7c98 GSEventRunModal + 160
39  UIKitCore                           0x000000010ee2237c -[UIApplication _run] + 868
40  UIKitCore                           0x000000010ee26374 UIApplicationMain + 124
41  planetTube                          0x00000001008a214c main + 100
2023-03-19 14:05:21.846279+0530 planetTube[97834:527225] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C5.1.1:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2023-03-19 14:05:21.847297+0530 planetTube[97834:527225] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C5.1.2:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2023-03-19 14:05:21.847706+0530 planetTube[97834:527231] [connection] nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke [C5] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2023-03-19 14:05:21.847810+0530 planetTube[97834:527231] TCP Conn 0x6000007f4000 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
2023-03-19 14:05:22.307289+0530 planetTube[97834:527223] [native] Manifest does not exist - creating a new one.

(null)
2023-03-19 14:05:22.386170+0530 planetTube[97834:527115] [native] [GESTURE HANDLER] Initialize gesture handler for view <RCTRootContentView: 0x12c50af90; reactTag: 1; frame = (0 0; 393 852); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x6000038e3bd0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000036c0500>>
```